# Composite recording creates empty video

Tags: java, webrtc, kurento

Here is my code to create composite video recording using java.but it creates blank video .not playing the stream.why?

```
mp       = kurento.createMediaPipeline();

WebRtcEndpoint webRtcEPRed = new WebRtcEndpoint.Builder(mp).build();
WebRtcEndpoint webRtcEPGreen = new WebRtcEndpoint.Builder(mp).build();

Composite composite = new Composite.Builder(mp).build();
HubPort hubPort1 = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();
HubPort hubPort2 = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();
HubPort hubPort3 = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();

RecorderEndpoint recorderEP =
    new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(mp, RECORDING_PATH + "twoside" + RECORDING_EXT).build();


webRtcEPRed.connect(hubPort1);
webRtcEPGreen.connect(hubPort2);

hubPort3.connect(recorderEP);

recorderEP.record();
```

Comment: Do you know if the webRTC streams are receiving video?  Are you exchanging and adding the webRTC ICE candidates correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my code as follows,Now it is working fine

```
  // Media pipeline
    pipeline = kurento.createMediaPipeline();


    Composite composite = new Composite.Builder(pipeline).build();

    HubPort hubPort1 = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();
    HubPort hubPort2 = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();
    HubPort hubPort3 = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();

    recorderEP =  new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(pipeline, RECORDING_PATH + "twosidess" + RECORDING_EXT).build();

    webRtcCaller.connect(webRtcCallee);
    webRtcCaller.connect(recorderEP);

    webRtcCaller.connect(hubPort1);
    webRtcCallee.connect(hubPort2);

    webRtcCallee.connect(webRtcCaller);

    hubPort3.connect(recorderEP);
    recorderEP.record();
```